# SQL Update Error + WHERE Clause Clarification

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have an edit form for my SQL Table which contains text boxes for the user to edit the details of the selected record. On load, the details/information of the selected record/row are inserted into the appropriate text boxes and once the user changes what they want, the whole record is updated by clicking the `Updatebtn`.

The connection is established successfully and the edit form populates the text boxes as expected. However, when I click the `Updatebtn` I receive the following error (though it may not be limited to the one error!)

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find stored procedure 'P'.

It highlights the `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

The `Updatebtn` code is as follows - Note I used and adapted the code from my Add button which functions well, so I know this method works. Please also check my WHERE Clause; I was unsure if that's the correct way to reference the record I have selected and want to update.

Additional information: The `midtxt.Text` in the WHERE Clause is populated by the forms load and contains the Members_ID of the selected index/item from the DataGridView.

```
Private Sub Updatebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Updatebtn.Click
    stcon = "Data Source =**.**.**.***;Initial Catalog=Members_Details;Integrated Security=False;User=UGSTUDIOLEADERSHIP;Password=****************;"
    con = New SqlConnection(stcon)

    con.Open()
    p(0) = New SqlParameter("@Members_ID", SqlDbType.Int)
    p(1) = New SqlParameter("@Gamer_Tag", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(2) = New SqlParameter("@Screenname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(3) = New SqlParameter("@First_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(4) = New SqlParameter("@Last_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(5) = New SqlParameter("@DoB", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(6) = New SqlParameter("@E_Mail_Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(7) = New SqlParameter("@Position", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(8) = New SqlParameter("@UG_Studio", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(9) = New SqlParameter("@Cautions", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(10) = New SqlParameter("@Record", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(11) = New SqlParameter("@Event_Attendance", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(12) = New SqlParameter("@Members_Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(13) = New SqlParameter("@GTA_V_Crew_Member", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(14) = New SqlParameter("@Games_Owned", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(15) = New SqlParameter("@Rep_Group", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
    p(0).Value = midtxt.Text
    p(1).Value = gttxt.Text
    p(2).Value = sntxt.Text
    p(3).Value = fntxt.Text
    p(4).Value = lntxt.Text
    p(5).Value = dobtxt.Text
    p(6).Value = emailtxt.Text
    p(7).Value = teamptxt.Text
    p(8).Value = ugptxt.Text
    p(9).Value = ugctxt.Text
    p(10).Value = recordtxt.Text
    p(11).Value = eventatxt.Text
    p(12).Value = memberstatcombo.Text
    p(13).Value = gtavcrewmembercombo.Text
    p(14).Value = gamesownedtxt.Text
    p(15).Value = RepGroupcombo.Text

    cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonsA SET(Members_ID=@Members_ID,Gamer_Tag=@Gamer_Tag,Screenname=@Screenname,First_Name=@First_Name,Last_Name=@Last_Name,DoB=@DoB,E_Mail_Address=@E_Mail_Address,Position=@Position,UG_Studio=@UG_Studio,Cautions=@Cautions,Record=@Record,Event_Attendance=@Event_Attendance,Members_Status=@Members_Status,GTA_V_Crew_Member=@GTA_V_Crew_Member,Games_Owned=@Games_Owned,Rep_Group=@Rep_Group WHERE Members_ID =)"(midtxt.Text), con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(0))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(1))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(2))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(3))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(4))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(5))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(6))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(7))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(8))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(9))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(10))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(11))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(12))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(13))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(14))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p(15))
    cmd.ExecuteScalar() 'This is where the Error is detected.
    MsgBox("Data has been saved!")

    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PersonsA", con)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "PersonsA")

    LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.DataMember = "PersonsA"
    LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

And help would be great! I'm also new to SQL in vb.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the extra set of parenthesis `()` around your SET clause in your update statement. something like this...

```
UPDATE PersonsA 
SET Members_ID=@Members_ID,
    Gamer_Tag=@Gamer_Tag,
    Screenname=@Screenname,
    First_Name=@First_Name,
    Last_Name=@Last_Name,
    DoB=@DoB,
    .
    .so on....
WHERE Members_ID = @var
```